# How can I get subclasses of abstract models in django for a migration?

Tags: django, abstract-class, data-migration

I have an abstract model, I'm writing a migration for all the subclasses. Instead of writing copies for each subclass I wanted to get all the subclasses of the abstract and apply the same action to them in a loop.

```
MyAbstractModel = apps.get_model("my_app", "MyAbstractModel")
subclasses = MyAbstractModel.__subclasses__()
```

But when I try to run the migration, I get:

```
LookupError: No installed app with label 'my_app'
```

How can I get the abstract model with apps.get_model so that I can call the subclasses on it?

If I do import the class directly with `from my_app.models import MyAbstractModel` then `MyAbstractModel.__subclasses__()` and all subsequent code works fine, but according to django docs, I should use `apps.get_model()`

Comment: Try putting your code in appconfig's ready function. I think you try to access application before it initialized by django.

Comment: it actually seems that AppConfig.get_model ignores abstract models (django 1.10.4)